# Flex mobile SWFLoader not loading

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex-mobile, swfloader

I'm trying to load a swf file into my flex mobile application with a swfloader however whenever I run the app the only thing that appears is a little square file icon. I've actually tried this with two swf files, both built in Flash CS Professionall but one in AS2 and one in AS3 and I get the same problem. I've tried setting autoLoad to true and it doesnt help. Also the complete event never runs, I'm assuming this is a result of the issue. Here is how I tried to make a SWFLoaders for both cases of which swf to load.

```
<s:SWFLoader id="mySWFLoader" bottom="10" left="10" source="/_flash/ffTalkSimpleSwf.swf" complete="setSwfMc()" />

<s:SWFLoader id="loader" width="75%" height="75%"
                                     source="/Module tester/ITPM2/common/shell1/controller.swf" autoLoad="true" creationComplete="done()"/>
```

I've tried embeding the source and it works for the second swf, however I don't want the source embeded because that swf needs to communicate with other files because it is the controller file of another application which I am trying to load.

Thanks

Comment: SWFLoader Code: <s:SWFLoader id="mySWFLoader" bottom="10" left="10" source="/_flash/ffTalkSimpleSwf.swf" complete="setSwfMc()" />

Comment: <s:SWFLoader id="loader" width="75%" height="75%"
                                         source="/Module tester/ITPM2/common/shell1/controller.swf" autoLoad="true" creationComplete="done()"/>

Comment: See if you got all your file paths set up correctly.  Do you get any error messages?

Comment: If this is happening on an Apple iOS device, dynamic loading of executable SWF is not permitted and will fail.